# Limit $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(\sum 1/n)/(\sum 1/e^n)\right]$

Tags: calculus

What is the limit of the following expression?

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[(\sum 1/n)/(\sum 1/e^n)\right]$$

Comment: I don't understand what values we are summing over.

Comment: 1/n is summing from 1 to infinity and 1/e^n is summing from 0 to infinity

Comment: If $n$ is the upper limit of the sums, you should use a different variable for the summation.  The upper one should be $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$.  This would save confusion.

Answer (score 2):

As the numerator diverges, while the denominator converges, the sum is $\infty$.